# Passing HttpPostedFileBase and other variables in ajax POST to mvc controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to post a file and some variables to my controller action using ajax, but I am getting null parameters for both of my variables.
Below is my ajax call

```
   $("#btn-upload").on("click", function () {
               var rows =$("[name='rows']").val();
               var formData = new FormData($('#excel-upload-form')[0]);
               var Data = formData+"&rows="+rows;
               $.ajax({
                   url: '/MVC/UploadExcel/UploadExcel',
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: Data,
                   cache: false,
                   contentType: false,
                   processData: false,
                   success: function (result) {
                       if (result=='True') {
                           $(".alert-success").show(); 
                       }
                       else {
                           $(".alert-danger").show();
                       }
                   },
                   error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                       $(".alert-danger").show();
                   },

               });
           });
```

and my controller action is

```
 [HttpPost]
        public bool UploadExcel(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile, int? rows)
        {
        var excelUtility = new ExcelUtilityService();
        bool success=false;
        if ((uploadedFile != null || uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0)&& rows !=null)
        {
        success = excelUtility.ProcessFile(uploadedFile, rows);
        }
        return success;
        }
```

If I pass only the file parameter in my ajax call it works fine but when I try to do it with multiple parameters e.g 'rows' in my code, both of the parameters become null in my controller action while post.

Comment: Use `formData.append('rows', rows);` instead of `var Data = formData+"&rows="+rows;` (with `data: formdata`)

Comment: Yes it worked @StephenMuecke thank you :)
Please post an answer so that I can mark it complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to add values to a `FormData` object, you need to use `.append()`.

Modify your script to

```
$("#btn-upload").on("click", function () 
   var rows =$("[name='rows']").val();
   var formData = new FormData($('#excel-upload-form')[0]);
   formData.append('rows', rows); // modify
   $.ajax({
       url: '/MVC/UploadExcel/UploadExcel',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData, // modify
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function (result) {
           ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the script modification from Stephen:

```
$("#btn-upload").on("click", function () 
   var rows =$("[name='rows']").val();
   var formData = new FormData($('#excel-upload-form')[0]);
   formData.append('rows', rows); // modify
   $.ajax({
       url: '/MVC/UploadExcel/UploadExcel',
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData, // modify
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function (result) {
           ....
```

If linking to parameters directly doesn't work with the formData.append() method above, I would recommend accessing them via:

```
Request["key-used-to-append"]
```

Example with your controller (rows variable assignment):

```
[HttpPost]
    public bool UploadExcel(HttpPostedFileBase uploadedFile)
    {
    var excelUtility = new ExcelUtilityService();
    var rows = Request["rows"];
    bool success=false;
    if ((uploadedFile != null || uploadedFile.ContentLength > 0)&& rows !=null)
    {
    success = excelUtility.ProcessFile(uploadedFile, rows);
    }
    return success;
    }
```